# How to check instance of fractional class for zero value in haskell?

Tags: haskell

If i have a value which is restricted to be fractional, is there a way i can check it either for being a zero value or for some neutral value? I'm trying to implement safe division with signature like this:

```
safe_idv :: (Fractional q) => q -> q -> Maybe q
```

I've checked at Hoogle if there is some method in minimal definition which can help, but to no avail.
Thanks in advance

Update: Since the question caused some confusion, I want to avoid changing the constraints on q, and pattern matching still requires Eq (i guess implicitly).

For following definition:

```
safe_div :: (Fractional q) => q -> q -> Result q
safe_div a 0 = Err ["dvision by zero"]
safe_div a b = Ok (a / b)
```

following error is raised:

```
    * Could not deduce (Eq q) arising from the literal `0'
      from the context: Fractional q
        bound by the type signature for:
                   safe_div :: forall q. Fractional q => q -> q -> Result q
        at AST2.hs:11:1-48
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq q) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            safe_div :: forall q. Fractional q => q -> q -> Result q
    * In the pattern: 0
      In an equation for `safe_div':
          safe_div a 0 = Err ["dvision by zero"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, simply `q == 0` should work. (Assuming you also put `Eq q` in the constraint - but you can avoid even this by pattern matching instead. )

Comment: `safe_div _ 0 = Nothing`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Pattern matching against a literal 0 still requires Eq, no? Like I agree it's the obvious right answer, but it doesn't avoid changing the signature.

Comment: @amalloy I'll trust you on that, I'm actually not sure (it's been a while since I did much with Haskell). Actually thinking about it it does make sense, usually with pattern matching you avoid needing `Eq` because you're matching directly on a constructor, but `q` is not going to be defined as an enumeration with `0` as one of the options, so I guess the apparent "pattern match" is desugared to an `== 0` check. But I'm not 100% confident about any of that and didn't even think of it tbh when adding that comment.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, pattern matching against literals is basically shorthand for a guard with an `==` check. Pattern matching against *constructors* avoids `Eq`, but can only be applied when you know (at least the outermost part of) the type, so you wouldn't be writing constraints on that type anyway. (e.g. pattern matching against `[]` only saves an `Eq` constraint for the element type because you're not comparing that; the `Eq [a]` constraint directly avoided you normally wouldn't have written anyway, because you know you're dealing with lists and that they are `Eq` if you have `Eq a`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the signature `safe_div :: (Fractional q) => q -> q -> Result q`, you can *only* use methods from `Fractional` or its superclasses on your `q` values.

(Or other predefined functions that impose no more constraints than `Fractional`, but those will ultimately have to be implemented by the class methods. So they can't do anything you couldn't do directly with the methods yourself.)

From [Fractional itself](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) that gives us:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
recip :: Fractional a => a -> a
fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a
```

Well none of those look terribly helpful. But `Num` is a superclass of `Fractional`, so we have those methods too:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
negate :: Num a => a -> a
abs :: Num a => a -> a
signum :: Num a => a -> a
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
```

These also aren't going to help us. `abs` and `signum` at first seem like they might, since their "purpose" is telling us certain properties about the number; `signum` even says this:

> For real numbers, the signum is either -1 (negative), 0 (zero) or 1 (positive).

Which sounds exactly the kind of thing we want! The only trouble is that `signum` communicates the result of its inspection as a value of the same type. If we couldn't tell if our number `x` is equal to zero, how are we going to tell whether `signum x` is equal to zero? We're right back at the problem we started with.

The fact is every single method of both `Fractional` and `Num` only ever returns a value of the (unknown) type implementing the class. That basically means if you don't know what they type actually is, it's impossible to get any information out of them; the only thing you can do with a value of an unknown `Fractional` type is pass it to another `Fractional` (or `Num`) method, which will also only give you back a value of the same unknown type. There's no way to compare it to anything (which would require something returning a `Bool`, `Ordering`, or at least a `Maybe`, `Either`, etc). There's no way to convert it to text so it can be shown to a user (which would require something returning a `String`, `Text`, etc). You can do further calculations, but the only thing we can ever learn is that the calculation didn't error out, and only by trying it and hoping (which is exactly what you're trying to avoid!).

The **only** way you can implement your desired function is to add more constraints. `Eq` is exactly the class of types which can be compared, and you want to compare values of your type, so it just makes sense that you will have to constrain your function to operate within this class of types.

However, anyone *calling* this function polymorphically is in the same boat. It's very useful for intermediate functions (like this one) to work with unknown `Fractional` types, so that they can be called with *any* fractional type. But at the outermost level where someone *first* decided to call one of these functions, it's only ever useful to call these with a concrete type they actually know something about. Nobody *wants* to do calculations on numbers where they can't inspect the result in any way! This means that even though your `safe_div` function (as it is currently written) cannot *assume* any details of any particular type (such as whether it can be compared for equality), it in fact will only ever realistically be called with specific types like `Double`, `Float`, etc, all of which do support `Eq`. So in practice adding the `Eq` constraint is hardly limiting who can call it.

I imagine the reason you don't want to change the constraint is that you've already coded up functions where you use this, and they only have `Fractional` constraints (meaning they can't call `safe_div :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> Result a`). Unfortunately they'll have to be updated to add the `Eq` constraint too. The fact is that the interface of **just** `Fractional` gives only the ability to do basic arithmetic. To do comparisons and branching calculations you need more. So *all* your functions that want to do more than basic arithmetic (and that includes any that call anything that does more than basic arithmetic, not just ones that do the comparison and branching themselves) need more constraints than just `Fractional`. Fortunately the same reasoning as above applies: it is extremely unlikely that you would ever need to call any of these functions with a type that **doesn't** support `Eq`, so there really is very little point in resisting the additional constraint.

Comment: It's interesting the `Fractional` differs from `Real` in this regard. (`Real` has `Ord` as a superclass, but doesn't seem to "need" it anymore than `Fractional` would.)

Comment: @chepner I suppose it's because `toRational :: Real a => a -> Rational` means you always *can* get information out of an unknown `Real` type. `Rational`s have order, so every `Real` type can at least be ordered that way. It also means `Real` can't support more abstract types like the function instance for `Num` that's always used as an example of why `Eq` shouldn't be a superclass of `Num`, so I guess when that change was being made similar arguments didn't apply to removing `Ord` from `Real`.